# Pug Multi line buffered text

Tags: html, pug

Is there a better way to output multi lined buffered text into a code block?

```
pre: code.language-html
    = '<div>\n'
    = '    <p>Hello</p>\n'
    = '</div>'
```

The formatting of this isn't nice, I would like it if I didn't have to place `/n` at the end of each line and wrap each individual line in quotes.

What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in [Pug (formerly Jade)](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html), however there are workarounds.

For one, your code would work, but you cannot break expressions across lines:

```
pre: code.language-html
  = new MyClass().render('<div>\n'    // SYNTAX ERROR!!
  = '    <p>Hello</p>\n'
  = '</div>')
```

So you could use your method for simple one-line expressions, but for multiline functions, objects, arrays, etc., this would fail.

Alternatively you could do all your work in *unbuffered* code, and then reference it in *buffered* code.

```
-
  var output = new MyClass().render('<div>\n'
    + '    <p>Hello</p>\n'
    + '</div>')
-
  let es6output = new MyClass().render(`
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  `) // if you want template literals
pre: code.language-html
  = output // unescaped (converts `<` to `&lt;`)
  != output // escaped
```

The feature you’re looking for would obviously be a great addition to the Pug syntax. In fact an issue has already been created: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2371